# Oracle built-in types

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql

How can I define a variable of specific data type in sql server like I do in Oracle

```
   Declare 
         var emp.empno%type;
         rec emp%rowtype;
```

in oracle when I define `var emp.empno%type` then the oracle engine convert the data type of 
 `var` to be the same data type of field `emp.empno` 
and when I define `rec emp%rowtype` the it convert the data type of `rec` to row data type 
 and this row contain all the fields of the table emp

I will be thankful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with SQL Server.
You can try to use user defined types, but that doesn't help much, as you can't modify the types after creating some objects using them.